# Bash script - variable content as a command to run

Tags: bash

I have a Perl script that gives me a defined list of random numbers that correspond to the lines of a file. Next I want to extract those lines from the file using `sed`.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$(cat last_queries.txt | wc -l)
var=$(perl test.pl test2 $count)
```

The variable `var` returns an output like: `cat last_queries.txt | sed -n '12p;500p;700p'`. The problem is that I can't run this last command. I tried with `$var`, but the output is not correct (if I run manually the command it works fine, so no problem there). What is the correct way to do this?

P.S: Sure I could do all the work in Perl, but I'm trying to learn this way, because it could help me in other situations.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

You just need to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$(cat last_queries.txt | wc -l)
$(perl test.pl test2 $count)
```

However, if you want to call your Perl command later, and that's why you want to assign it to a variable, then:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$(cat last_queries.txt | wc -l)
var="perl test.pl test2 $count" # You need double quotes to get your $count value substituted.

...stuff...

eval $var
```

As per Bash's help:

```
~$ help eval
eval: eval [arg ...]
    Execute arguments as a shell command.

    Combine ARGs into a single string, use the result as input to the shell,
    and execute the resulting commands.

    Exit Status:
    Returns exit status of command or success if command is null.
```

Comment: Without `eval` this won't work as-expected. Try `var='printf "%s\n" "first item" "second item" "third item"` and compare `$var` to `eval "$var"`. The first is simply wrong, for the reasons described in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: ...that is to say: `$(perl test.pl test2 $count)` should be `eval "$(perl test.pl test2 $count)"` to avoid the bugs that BashFAQ #50 documents.

Comment: That works (I also had trouble with a command line containing "`|`", like in the question). If the ***output (to standard output) needs to be captured***, then it can be done by `someoutput=$(eval $var)` instead of just `eval $var`. Perhaps extend the answer a little bit?

Answer (score 192):

You are probably looking for `eval $var`.

Comment: This worked when `$($cmd))` failed. It always says command not found. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There're 2 basic ways of executing a string command in a shell script whether it's given as parameter or not here's.

```
COMMAND="ls -lah"
$(echo $COMMAND)
```

or

```
COMMAND="ls -lah"
bash -c $COMMAND
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a bit. But do you have an idea why `bash -c "cd /home/user/dev/"` is not working?

Comment: @andylib93 `cd` only affects the current process, if you run `bash -c "cd /home/user/dev/"`, then it will start a new `bash` process and run `cd` within that process. The child process will change directory just fine, but that will have no effect on the shell where you ran the `bash` command.

Answer (score 3):

```
line=$((${RANDOM} % $(wc -l < /etc/passwd)))
sed -n "${line}p" /etc/passwd
```

just with your file instead.

In this example I used the file /etc/password, using the special variable `${RANDOM}` (about which I learned here), and the `sed` expression you had, only difference is that I am using double quotes instead of single to allow the variable expansion.

Answer (score 3):

In the case where you have multiple variables containing the arguments for a command you're running, and not just a single string, you should *not* use eval directly, as it will fail in the following case:

```
function echo_arguments() {
  echo "Argument 1: $1"
  echo "Argument 2: $2"
  echo "Argument 3: $3"
  echo "Argument 4: $4"
}

# Note we are passing 3 arguments to `echo_arguments`, not 4
eval echo_arguments arg1 arg2 "Some arg"
```

Result:

```
Argument 1: arg1
Argument 2: arg2
Argument 3: Some
Argument 4: arg
```

Note that even though "Some arg" was passed as a single argument, `eval` read it as two.

Instead, you can just use the string as the command itself:

```
# The regular bash eval works by jamming all its arguments into a string then
# evaluating the string. This function treats its arguments as individual
# arguments to be passed to the command being run.
function eval_command() {
  "$@";
}
```

Note the difference between the output of `eval` and the new `eval_command` function:

```
eval_command echo_arguments arg1 arg2 "Some arg"
```

Result:

```
Argument 1: arg1
Argument 2: arg2
Argument 3: Some arg
Argument 4:
```

Comment: To avoid the evaluation of each element after space, as in your first example with eval, wrap it with single quotes:  `eval 'echo_arguments arg1 arg2 "Some arg"'`. Then the output will be as in your second example.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `"$whatever"` is shorter _and_ more reliable than `eval "$whatever"`.

Answer (score 0):

Better ways to do it

Using a function:

```
# define it
myls() {
    ls -l "/tmp/test/my dir"
}

# run it
myls
```

Using an array:

```
# define the array
mycmd=(ls -l "/tmp/test/my dir")

# run the command
"${mycmd[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd="ls -atr ${HOME} | tail -1" <br/>
echo "$cmd"  <br/>
VAR_FIRST_FILE=$( eval "${cmd}" )  <br/>
```

or

```
cmd=("ls -atr ${HOME} | tail -1")  <br/>
echo "$cmd"  <br/>
VAR_FIRST_FILE=$( eval "${cmd[@]}" )
```