# Unable to use grep for a command and excecute the shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have created a shell script to execute 5 commands from a file called elist.txt

```
ps -ef | grep user | grep 'process -s 9000' | cut -c -15 | cut -c 10-
ps -ef | grep user | grep 'process -s 9001' | cut -c -15 | cut -c 10-
ps -ef | grep user | grep 'process -s 9002' | cut -c -15 | cut -c 10-
ps -ef | grep user | grep 'process -s 9003' | cut -c -15 | cut -c 10-
```

The shell script is as follows

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin"
input="/home/user/script/list.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
echo $($line)
done < "$input"
```

output:

```
error: garbage option

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

Comment: It seems you are using a version of `ps` that a) does not accept `-ef` and b) does not print a useful error message.  Possibly `ps` is a wrapper (or an alias) that is mangling the call to the system `ps` (which is not giving a useful error message).

Comment: The command works when typed on console

Comment: If you execute `set -x`, then you'll probably see what is wrong.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I think it's actually because `$($line)` doesn't treat `|` as a shell pipe, just a normal character

Comment: ++ input=/home/user/script/elist.txt
++ IFS=
++ read -r line
+++ ps -ef '|' grep user
error: garbage option

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
++ echo

++ IFS=
++ read -r line

Comment: Indeed, `|` is getting passed as an argument to ps.  And ps is printing a useless error messags.

Comment: Never, never, respond with a usage statement on a usage error.  Always print a terse error message describing which option is incorrect.  If the user wants a usage statement, they can ask for it with `-h` or `--help`.

Comment: Why are you using this while loop instead of just `"$input"` or `. "$input"`?

Comment: it looks like that the whole line is not in the variable "$line". What's the output of `echo $line`. I normally replace the blanks with '_' in the file and in the loop replaced with blanks before the execution. HTH

Comment: Actually I am totally new to this stuff. Can someone help me out on what I am doing wrong here, Because when I provide a simple commands like ls and ls -al it's working. Similarly ps -ef is also working once I start filtering the result using "|". I am getting the error.

Comment: @Aleksandar echo $line ==> ps -ef | grep enmac

Comment: Anyone ..... ??

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this too. People usually do not recommend to use *eval* at all.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin"
input="/home/user/script/list.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
bash -c "$line"
done < "$input"
```

Regards!

Comment: agree, that's another possible solution ;-)

Comment: This does not address the concerns with eval though.  It is still doing eval, just invoking another shell to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this script with eval which is a similar solution described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6002329/6778826

```
export PATH="/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin"
input="/home/user/script/list.txt"
while read -r line
do
  eval "$line"
done <$input
```